# Tomcat resource access limit based on DB

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat

I have web-app on Tomcat. I need to limit access to all its resources only for authenticated users. User logins and credentials are located in some DB table with according columns. What's the easiest way to implement this in the case database schema is not to be modified.
I found some options:

1. Extend tomcat JDBCRealm. It requires additional table for roles (that's why extending instead of using standard), but i have simplified case of just one role.
2. Implement JAAS LoginModule based on DB. If there is existing opensource solutions with license for usage in proprietary software let me know about it.
3. After successful login put an user in session attribute. Then implement servlet filter that checks for presence of that attribute in the session.

Probably there are simpler options. So it will be interesting to see them.